# Bootstrap files are not loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

[My bootstrap folder structure in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXJFW.jpg)
Am using spring mvc if i do dispatcher servlet configuration in web.xml the bootstrap files are not loading to the browser otherwise if CDN for the bootstrap css everything is fine why local files are not loading in eclipse

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta name="description" content="">
                <meta name="author" content="">
                <title>Login Page</title>
                <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
                 <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
                     <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
                 <link href="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
                <!-- Custom CSS -->
                 <link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
                <!-- Custom Fonts -->
                 <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mine/css/MyCss.css"></link>    
              <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In Here</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <form id="loginForm" role="form" action="login" method="post">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class=" col-xs-15 control-label">
                                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail or Username" name="userName" type="text" autofocus>
                                            </div>
                                             </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                             <div class=" col-xs-15 control-label">
                                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="login" /> 
                                       <br>

                                       <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Registration Yourself
                                             <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a href="pages/StudentEnrollmentFromAdmin.jsp">Student</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="ParentsByAdmin.jsp">Parent</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="TeacherByAdmin.jsp">Teacher</a></li>
                                               </ul>
                                            &nbsp<span><u><a href="#">Forgot your password ?</a></u></span>
                                        </div>
                                     </fieldset>

                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- jQuery -->

                <script src="Mine/scripts/loginscript.js"></script>
                <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
                <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
                <script src="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
                <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
                <script src="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript"  src="dist/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>


            <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                    <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
                    </param-value>
                    </init-param>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>
                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This is am adding 3rd time no solving please help me

Answer (score 0):

We have to put all static bootstrap content inside resource folder

Example Webcontent/resources/Bootstrap files

then configure below lines in springContext.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```